# Library-code library mismaches for google data api GA4

Tags: python, api, google-apps-script, analytics

Because Google is still changing their api's for ga4, I get mismatches in function names and parameter lists. I tried api v.11 that chatGPT uses, I also tries the latest version .16. Right now, I get a runtime error " File "d:\workspaceGA\ga4export\ga4base.py", line 49, in sample_run_report
one_of=DimensionValue.OneOf(
AttributeError: type object 'DimensionValue' has no attribute 'OneOf'" Any ideas? It becomes a shell game, I would fix one problem like this, then something else errors out elsewhere, a function, class or variable name errors out.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./')
from globals import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = GLOBAL_KEY_FILE_LOCATION
MEASUREMENT_ID = GLOBAL_MEASUREMENT_ID

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import (
    DateRange,
    Dimension,
    Metric,
    RunReportRequest,
    CohortSpec,
    Cohort,
    DimensionValue,
    CohortsRange,
    CohortReportSettings,
)


def sample_run_report(start_date_day, end_date):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(KEY_FILE_LOCATION, scopes=SCOPES)
    client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient(credentials=credentials)

    start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date_day, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

    while start_date <= end_date:
        # set the end_date for the current day
        current_end_date = (start_date + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        request = RunReportRequest(
            property=f"properties/{MEASUREMENT_ID}",
            dimensions=[
                Dimension(name="customEvent:n20_page_url"),
                Dimension(name="customDimension:n20_nick_name")
            ],
            metrics=[Metric(name="eventCount")],
            date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date=start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), end_date=current_end_date)],
            cohort_spec=CohortSpec(
                cohorts=[
                    Cohort(
                        dimension=DimensionValue(
                            value="",
                            one_of=DimensionValue.OneOf(
                                value=DimensionValue.StringValue(
                                    value="customDimension:n20_nick_name"
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        name="",
                    )
                ],
                cohorts_range=CohortsRange(start_offset=0, end_offset=0),
                cohort_report_settings=CohortReportSettings(),
            )
        )

        response = client.run_report(request)

        print(f"Report result for {start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}:")
        for row in response.rows:
            print(row.dimension_values[0].value, row.dimension_values[1].value, row.metric_values[0].value)

        # set the start_date for the next day
        start_date += timedelta(days=1)


def main():
    start_date_day = '2023-01-01'
    end_date = '2023-03-10'
    sample_run_report(start_date_day, end_date)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```